# Need help converting strings from a text file into a float

Tags: python

```
holder = []
with open('Weather_final.txt','r') as weather_contents:
        weather = weather_contents.readlines()
        for lines in weather:
            column = lines.strip()
            holder.append(float(column))
           
        print(holder)
        for x in holder:
            print(x)
        
        print(float(min(x[1])))
```

I get this error message when i run the program 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: '62, 47, 16''. I want the code to find the largest and smallest number in each column, there are 3 columns in each row.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a small snapshot of your text file?

Comment: This should help [Getting the min of each column of a CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378137/finding-the-minimum-of-each-column-of-a-csv-file-using-python)

Comment: I added the snapshot but my rep is to low to post the pic so it made a separate link.

Answer (score 0):

For each row, use `row.split(', ')` to [split](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string into a list. Then you can use min and max to find the smallest and largest value in the list and convert them to floats, and store them where you want.

```
for row in weather:
    columns = row.split(", ")
    smallest = float(min(columns))
    largest = float(max(columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the error message it seems you are unable to convert the string `'62, 47, 16'` into a float.

In order to do this I would first split each number into a list using the `split()`method and then iterate over each item in the list and convert to a float. An example I put together can be seen below:

```
x = '62, 47, 16'
x_list = x.split(',')
x_float = []
for i in range(len(x_list)):
  x_float.append(float(x_list[i]))
print(max(x_float))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'split()' to separate values on each row. Use 'split(",")' if they are separated by comma.
Use map() to convert all values on each line to float

```
holder = []
with open('Weather_final.txt','r') as weather_contents:
    weather = weather_contents.readlines()
    for lines in weather:
        #Use map to convert values on each line to float and to list
        column = list(map(float, lines.strip().split()))
        holder.append(column)
    print(holder)
    for x in holder:
        print(x)
    # Min and Max of each column
    for i in range(3):
        print("min of column {}: {}".format(i+1, min([x[i] for x in holder])))
        print("min of column {}: {}".format(i+1, max([x[i] for x in holder])))
```